# how to use background-size: cover and background-position in CSS3 ?

Tags: css, background, background-image

Is the a way to use `background-size: cover` and `background-position` at the same time on a class ?

Example :

```
.image { 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: -200px 0;
    background-image: url('...');
}
```

The property `background-position` doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** : Add `margin-top: -200px;`